# Sliding Animation Stutters in Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, accordion, slide

I have an accordion menu with tabs. When you click on the tabs, information is displayed below one of them, by sliding up and down smoothly.

The problem is that there is a stutter in the animation, during `slideUp` and `slideDown`. I also tried `animate` and adjusting some of the css, but I can't figure it out.

If it helps, here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9w8takr7/8/).

HTML:

```
 <div class="project-container">
 
 
 These don't slide well:
     <ul class="project-nav">
  <li class="project-tab" id="project-tab-1"><a id="project-tab-link" href="#" class="active">Tab 1</a>
    <section class="is-open">
    <p id="current-project-title">TITLE</p>
    <p>TEXT HERE</p>
    </section>
  </li>
  <li class="project-tab" id="project-tab-2"><a id="project-tab-link" href="#">Tab 2</a>
    <section>
INFO HERE<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
     </section>
  </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        
<br>
But this slides VERY well:
<br>
             <button class="toggle-info">toggle slider<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></button>
             <section class="info-container">
             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </section>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Tabs = {
  
  el: {
    nav: $(".project-nav"),
    tabs: $(".project-nav > .project-tab > a"),
    panels: $(".project-nav > .project-tab > section"),
  },

  init: function() {
    Tabs.bindUIActions();
  },
  bindUIActions: function() {
    Tabs.el.nav
      .on(
        'click', 
        '.project-tab > a:not(.active)', 
        function(event) {
          Tabs.deactivateAll();
          Tabs.activateTab(event);
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      );
  },
  
  deactivateAll: function() {
    Tabs.el.tabs.removeClass("active");
    Tabs.el.panels.removeClass("is-open").slideUp('slow');
  },
  activateTab: function(event) {
    $(event.target)
      .addClass("active")
      .next()
      .addClass("is-open").slideDown('slow');
  }
};

Tabs.init();   




////// Slide Doesn't Work For Tabs
$('.project-tab section.is-open').slideDown('slow');



////// Slide Works For Toggle Button
$('.toggle-info').click(function() {
    $('.info-container').slideToggle('slow');
    $("i", this).toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This your problem

```
.project-nav section, .project-nav section.is-open, .project-nav .project-tab a:hover, .project-nav .project-tab a.active, #current-project-link,
#current-project-link:hover, .project-nav section.is-open, .project-nav section {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
```

You add transition css to slide element, it make slide effect not working correctly, you must remove it

you can try this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pajarft/dc9m7sq5/1/)

Comment: You're right! That fixed the stutter opening. Do you know how to fix the movement while closing? Right now, if you click on one, the other snaps shut, rather than closing slowly.

Also, it looks like the first time Tab 2 is clicked, it is automatically open, then closes, then opens again. But only the first time it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired effect using CSS, instead of jquery. I used `max-height` transitions to make the tabs slide both up *and* down smoothly.

Here's the updated [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/9w8takr7/11)

And here's the new CSS:

```
///// RESPONSIVE ACCORDION TO TABS


.project-container {
    display: block;
}

.project-nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.project-nav a:active{
    opacity:1;
}

.project-nav .project-tab { 
    display: inline; 
  } 

.project-nav > .project-tab > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #00A88C;
  border: solid 1px #00A88C;
  border-radius: 0px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width:40%;
  font-size: 30pt;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

#project-tab-1 {
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-left: 7%;
}

#project-tab-2 {
    margin-left: 2%;
}

#project-tab-link:hover { 
    background-color: #13ebc7;
    border-color: #13ebc7;
} 

#project-tab-link.active {
    color: #00A88C!important;
  background-color: rgba(19, 235, 199, 0)!important;
}

#project-tab-link.active:hover {
   border-color: #00A88C;
}

.project-nav section {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  float: left;
  color:#5c5c5c;
  overflow: hidden; 
  border: solid 1px #00A88C;
  width:100%;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.project-nav section.is-open {
  position: static;
  opacity: 100;
}

.project-tab section p {
    font-family:'century gothic';
    padding: 0px 30px;
}

.project-tab section p:empty {
  display: none;
}

#current-project-title{
  font-size: 16pt;
}

#current-project-link {
  float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #00A88C;
    color:#fff;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: auto;
}

#current-project-link:hover {
     background: #13ebc7;
}

.project-nav section, .project-nav section.is-open, .project-nav .project-tab a:hover, .project-nav .project-tab a.active, #current-project-link,
#current-project-link:hover, .project-nav section.is-open, .project-nav section {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 730px) {
    #front-page-textbox{
        background: #0f2347;
        color: #fff;
    }
.project-container {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
  .project-nav .project-tab a {
    display: block;
    width:100%;
    border-radius: 0px;
  }
    
    #project-tab-1, #project-tab-2 {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
}
    
    .project-nav .project-tab a.active {
    border: solid 1px #13ebc7; 
    }

  .project-nav section {
    margin:0;
      position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  float: none;
  max-height:0;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  opacity: 100;
  }
    
.project-nav section.is-open {
    border-radius: 0px;
    border-top: none;
    max-height: 1200px;
}
    .project-tab > a:after {
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        content: "\e080"; 
        float: right;
        font-size: 20pt;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .project-tab > a.active:after{
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        content: "\e114";
        float:right;
        font-size: 20pt;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }



/// TOGGLE BUTTON

.toggle-info {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #00A88C;
    font-size: 30pt;
}

.toggle-info i{
    font-size: 10pt;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    display: block;
}

.toggle-info:hover {
     background-color: #13ebc7;
}

.toggle-info, .toggle-info:hover {
        -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}
    
.info-container{
     padding: 10px 15px;
border: solid 1px #00A88C;
}
```